# how to update the pending payment orders to cancel and the script in cronjob

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-status

Below code is working but when trying to add time doesn't work see other section of code.

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> 'pending_payment'])
                        ->load();
                        
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderState = 'canceled';
    $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
    $order->save();
}
```

when added time in code and doesn't work

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400;
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> 'pending_payment'])
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
                        ->load();
                        
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderState = 'canceled';
    $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file **status.php** on your magento root

Add this code and hit the file in browser `like: localhost/magento/status.php` to change **pending_payment** orders to **cancel**

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400;
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> 'pending_payment'])
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
                        ->load();
                        
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderState = 'canceled';
    $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: only set this program true if orders are older than 24 hours?

Comment: @Bayzel updated the answer

Comment: it was working  earlier before the new edit but now it not working at all.

Comment: i have edited your code and it working now